# how to read the json object and send it to an email in pure nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

I am stuck to send my json object using pure nodejs, don't know what to write in post.js to send the object to a email using only pure nodejs,
this is my ajax request

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#contact").submit(function () {
        var data = {};
        $.each($(this).serializeArray(), function (key, value) {
            data[value.name] = value.value;
        });
        data.interest = [data.interest1, data.interest2, data.interest3];
        delete data.interest1;
        delete data.interest2;
        delete data.interest3;
        console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "post.js",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#contact").addClass('success');
            },
            error: function () {
                $("#contact").addClass('error');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: Your question is far too broad. It looks like you haven't even gotten as far as looking at a basic "How to write a simple web server in Node" guide.

Comment: when you do `console.log(data);` after delete statements what does it show?